# Prove $2^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to prove the following equation above. So far I have:
\begin{align}
2^{2n} &= (1+1)^{2n}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}1^k1^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} & \text{(By the Binomial Theorem)}
\end{align}

I know I have to use the following identity somehow:
$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}$$

How do I split my summation to get what I'm looking for? Thanks!

**EDIT: HERE IS MY SOLUTION**
\begin{align*}
2^{2n} &= (1+1)^{2n}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}1^k1^{2n-k} & \text{(By the Binomial Theorem)}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{2n-k} & \text{(Binomial Symmetry)}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{k-1}\\
&= \binom{2n}{0} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{k-1}\\
&= \binom{2n}{0} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k} & \text{(By Identity listed above)}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hint: Add in the missing second half, from $n+1$ to $2n+1$.  We do not need the identity you quoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}=\frac{2^{2n+1}}{2}=2^{2n}$$

Using the relation $$\binom{2n+1}{k}=\binom{2n+1}{2n+1-k}$$ for $0 \le k \le n$.

Comment: I'm confused how you can just change the upper bound of the summation like that.

Comment: I added a relation used to get the equality of the sums.

Answer (score 4):

$$ 2^{2n}=\frac12\cdot 2^{2n+1}=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}{2n+1\choose k}=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n\left({2n+1\choose k}+{2n+1\choose 2n+1-k}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use induction:

For $n=1$:

$2^2 = \binom{3}{0}+\binom{3}{1}$, true.

For $m=n+1$:

$2^{2n+2}=4\cdot 2^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k} + \binom{2n+2}{n+1} = 2^{2n} + \binom{2n+2}{n+1} = 2^{2n} + \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!^2}$

Comment: ...well, something won't work, I am thinking on it.